# Call WebEx Outlook AddIn from Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, outlook-addin, excel-2013

I'm automating most of an Outlook calendar invite but struggling with calling a COM Addin. I've figured out the ProgID to specify it correctly but can't see a way to list the available Objects.

```
Dim OutlookApp As Object, OutlookInvite As Object
Dim addIn As COMAddIn, automationObject As Object
Set OutlookApp = GetObject(class:="Outlook.Application") 
SDM = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").Value
Set OutlookInvite = OutlookApp.CreateItem(1)
With OutlookInvite
    .MeetingStatus = 1
    .Subject = "foo"
    .Body = "bar"
    .Recipients.Add SDM
    .Start = Now()
    .Duration = 30
    .BusyStatus = 2
    .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15
    .ReminderSet = True
    Set addIn = OutlookApp.COMAddIns("WebExOI.Addin")
    Set automationObject = addIn.Object
    automationObject.AddPersonalRoom
    .Display
End With
```

The AddPersonalRoom is just my best guess but it does nothing. I'm missing a trick.

Comment: You could try to change registry like this: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\15.0\outlook\resiliency\addinlist
RG_SZ= add-in name
Value = 1 For more information, please refer to this link: https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/always-load-an-outlook-addin/

Comment: Thanks @AlinaLi but I am unable to alter Registry keys due to Company policy. The AddIn is available to all users and works OK manually. I need to find a way, using VBA, to launch it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because testing is now impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Including the webex personal room is easy and does not require the use of the webex plugin.  Just include your personal room link, which you can get from opening your personal room in webex, going to meeting info and copying the link, and then just include in the meeting description/body field.  The URL should be something like this.   https://.webex.com/meet/

Comment: Thanks @BrianYoksh, but I am now in a different company from when I asked this question four years ago so I can't test your answer.